# Как достать данные из mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Как взять данные из mongodb?
Вот есть такая структура базы:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   local : {
      email : String,
      password : String,
      name : String,
      urlz : {
        longurl : String,
        shorturl : String,
        clicks : 0
      } 
  }
});
```

Как мне поиском достать оттуда все longurl?
Пытаюсь через `db.find({и сюда уже миллион всего перепробовал и не находит})`.
Помогите кто знает пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы хотите использовать `longurl` как критерия поиска или что?

Comment: @user3100115 я хочу получить в json формате [{longurl : "url"},{longurl:"url2"}] и т.д.. Мне надо достать из базы все longurl чтобы потом в ангуларе из longurl получить именно url и вывести их.

Answer (score 5):

Вот такая команда вернет список записей, содержащих только параметр longurl

```
db.имя_коллекции.find({}, {_id:0, urlz.longurl:1 })
```

Comment: отсутствует `"` должно быть `"urlz.longurl": 1`